# How can I add a tooltip to a choropleth in Folium and get rid of 'NoneType' error?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, folium

Using folium in jupyter notebooks, I am trying to draw a choropleth which displays info when I hover over the geographical boundary. I am unable to get the tool tip functionality to work

I tried plotting the map alone with no child layer of hover -> works just fine
I tried adding hover but not tooltip -> works just fine
when I add too tip I get the error " TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable"
I have tried converting colA into a string datatype but it does not make a difference

```
m = folium.Map(location=[-36.8485, 174.7633], zoom_start=10, tiles='CartoDB positron')

# Adjust the opacity of the base map tiles
m.get_root().html.add_child(folium.Element('<style>.leaflet-tile-pane{opacity: 0.6 !important;}</style>'))

merged_df['Statistical area 2 description'] =  merged_df['Statistical area 2 description'].astype(str)
merged_df.crs = 'EPSG:2193' 
style_function = lambda x: {'fillColor': '#ffffff', 
                            'color':'#000000', 
                            'fillOpacity': 0.1, 
                            'weight': 0.1}
highlight_function = lambda x: {'fillColor': '#000000', 
                                'color':'#000000', 
                                'fillOpacity': 0.50, 
                                'weight': 0.1}
hover = folium.features.GeoJson(
    merged_df,
    style_function=style_function, 
    control=False,
    highlight_function=highlight_function, 
        tooltip=folium.features.GeoJsonTooltip(
        fields=['Statistical area 2 description'],
        aliases=['SA2 description'],
        style=("background-color: white; color: #333333; font-family: arial; font-size: 12px; padding: 10px;"),
        localize=True
    )

)
m.add_child(hover)
m.keep_in_front(hover)


folium.Choropleth(
    geo_data=merged_df,
    name='choropleth',
    data =merged_df,
    columns = ['MESHBLOCK_2018', 'mean_merged_HbA1C'],
    key_on="feature.properties.MESHBLOCK_2018",  
    nan_fill_color='grey',
    nan_fill_opacity=0.4,
    fill_color = 'YlGnBu', #YlOrBr,'OrRd', #colormap, #'OrRd',
    fill_opacity=0.7,
    line_opacity=0.2,
    legend_name="Average HbA1C",
 
).add_to(m)

folium.LayerControl().add_to(m)

m
```

> I get the following error:
>
> 1094 def warn_for_geometry_collections(self):
> 1095     """Checks for GeoJson GeometryCollection features to warn user about incompatibility."""
> 1096     geom_collections = [
> 1097         feature.get("properties") if feature.get("properties") is not None else key
> 1098         for key, feature in enumerate(self._parent.data["features"])
> 1099         if feature["geometry"]["type"] == "GeometryCollection"
> 1100     ]
> 1101     if any(geom_collections):
> 1102         warnings.warn(
> 1103             "{} is not configured to render for GeoJson GeometryCollection geometries. "
> 1104             "Please consider reworking these features: {} to MultiPolygon for full functionality.\n"
> (...)
> 1108             UserWarning,
> 1109         )
>
> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
>
> merged_df is a dataframe with a geometry column showing multipolygon boundaries.